# need destructor to deallocate memory space even if all the items have been popped

Tags: c++, stack

Do I need to a destructor  for class lstack even if all the elements have been popped?
Please help me  with this.

```
~lstack()
             {
                if(top==NULL)
                   return;
                node *tmp;
                while(top!=NULL)
                {
                   tmp=top;
                   top=top->link;
                   delete tmp;
                }
             }    
int main()
    {
        lstack s;
        s.push(11);
        s.push(101);
        s.push(99);
        s.push(78);
        cout<<"Item Popped = "<<s.pop()<<endl;
        cout<<"Item Popped = "<<s.pop()<<endl;
        cout<<"Item Popped = "<<s.pop()<<endl;
        cout<<"Item Popped = "<<s.pop()<<endl;
        getch();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What if they haven't all been popped?

Comment: Of course we need if they are not popped. But I was wanting to make sure is it mandatory or not although all the items have been popped

Comment: Depends. What is `lstack`?

Comment: what do you mean by depends

Comment: @RaviKasaudhan Provide some details on the implementation of lstack. Is it a linked list? what do the nodes contain? just ints? When you pop, you return just an int? If so, the node is only part of the implementation and it's your job to deallocate it during the pop.

Comment: @RaviKasaudhan: If there is no work for the destructor to do, then you don't need the destructor.

Comment: @AlexanderKondratskiy Yes it is a linked list and the node contains just int and pointer to its similar type.

Comment: The dtor is a bit verbose: `while (Node* tmp = top) { top=top->link; delete tmp; }` is sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

If you are writing the class, and the class manages resources like memory on the free store, you should include the destructor.  That way, the users of your class -- whether other programmers or yourself in the future -- don't need to remember to pop all elements of the stack as a prerequisite for memory leak-free code. Your use of 'delete' suggests you need the destructor.

Users certainly wouldn't expect such a requirement.

Even if you //did// try to impose such a rule through documentation, and a conscientious programmer tried to follow it, the possibility of exceptions (which are handled outside the normal flow of control) would mean that sometimes a user couldn't empty the stack, even if he/she wanted to.

The destructor should be written so that it handles the case of an empty stack (as yours seems to).

Answer (score 2):

All classes which can be constructed on the stack need a destructor. If you don't declare one, a destructor will be generated which simply destroys all members of the object (obviously, destroying built-in types does nothing).

For a class allocating any resource, you always want a destructor: if something goes wrong and an exception is thrown you would otherwise leak memory. Also, it is an awkward interface to require that the content of an object is removed before it can be destroyed safely.

Finally, not that the standard C++ library has a stack class template: `std::stack<T>`.

The implementation of the destructor you posted is unnecessary complex! It can be simplified:

```
lstack::~lstack()
{
    while(top!=NULL)
    {
        std::unique_ptr<node> tmp(top);
        top=top->link;
    }
}
```

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Objects can be constructed on the heap without being destructible. Obviously, if you can't destroy them, they will leak but the language doesn't prevent that from happening. On the other hand, if you try to create an object on the stack which doesn't have an accessible destructor, the compiler will refuse to let you create an object because the object is destroyed when the end of the block is reached.

Comment: Yes, I suppose that's true.  However, not being on the stack isn't sufficient for not needing a destructor (apologies for the triple negative!).  Consider `struct Foo { private: ~Foo(); }; struct Bar { Foo x; ~Bar() {} };`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: yes. ... but if you don't define a destructor for `Bar` you can still allocate a `Bar` object. I'm not proposing to do so as memory leaks are not a good idea, though.